# Оптимальная алгоритмизация

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Добрый день.

Есть алгоритм, который можно записать двумя способами. 
Первый способ (примеры не транслировал):

```
for(i=0;i!=max;++i){
if(flag==true) fun1(int); else fun2(int,double);
}

if(flag==true) fun3(int,double,float); else fun4(int,double,float,char);
```

Второй способ:

```
if(flag==true){

for(i=0;i!=max;++i) {fun1(int);}

fun3(int,double,float);

}
else{

for(i=0;i!=max;++i) {fun2(int,double);}

fun4(int,double,float,char);

}
```

Оба эти способа имеют недостатки:

В первом способе есть потери быстродействия, так как условие проверяется каждый раз в цикле.

Во втором способе два раза повторяется цикл. Это плохо, так как при изменении параметров цикла (например параметра max), придется править в двух местах и легко забыть, что надо поправить и в другом цикле.

Вопрос:

1. Как надо сделать, чтобы и потерь быстродействия не было, и править надо было в одном месте. Не городить же ради такого простого дела шаблоны цикла с переменным числом параметров.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Коллеги приводят разные варианты решений этого конкретного примера. Но вопрос не в этом конкретном примере. Вопрос как решать общий случай. Для этого конкретного примера оптимальное решение такое (назовем его третий вариант, пример не транслировал):

```
class T1{
public:
run1(){fun1(int);}
run2(){fun3(int,double,float);}
};

class T2{
public:
run1(){fun2(int,double);}
run2(){fun4(int,double,float,char);}
};

template<class T> alg(T t){
for(i=0;i!=max;++i) {t.run1();}
t.run2();
};

main(){

T1 t1;
T2 t2;

if(flag==true){
alg<T1>(t1);
}
else{
alg<T2>(t2);
}

}
```

в этом третьем варианте нет проверки внутри цикла и вместе с тем если надо править параметры цикла, то править придется только в одном месте - в шаблонной функции alg. Но решение получилось слишком многословным для такой пустяковой задачи. Нужен более общий подход.

Comment: Т.е. проверка `flag==true` это у вас самое трудозатратное место в программе?

Comment: Это просто пример. Если этот цикл самый глубоковложеный, то там любая лишняя команда умножается на все внешние циклы и в итоге быстродействие сильно падает.

Comment: Ну так используйте второй вариант, а все параметры, которые могут измениться вынесите перед условием в переменные

Comment: В первом случае, [оптимизирующий компилятор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) запросто вынесет инвариант цикла из цикла. Во втором случае, заведите доп. локальную переменную, например, `end`, которая инициализируется перед циклами, а в циклах сравнивайте с `end`: `i!=end`. Таким образом, изменения можно будет вносить в одном единственном месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря не уверен,  но думаю функтор облегчит выполнение

```
// функции для проверки
void f1() {std::cout << 1 << '\n';}
void f2() {std::cout << 2 << '\n';}
void f3() {std::cout << 3 << '\n';}
void f4() {std::cout << 4 << '\n';}
class Fun  {
    int k;
public:
    Fun(int max) : k(max) {}
    void operator ()(bool b = false) {   // inline
        int n = k;
        if(b) {
            while(n--)  f1();
            f3();
        }
        else {
            while(n--)  f2();
            f4();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{  
    Fun obj(3);
    obj();
    obj(1);
    return 0;
}
```

не уверен, потому что не знаю цель вашей задачи, и еще можно функции содержать в классе как статические закрытые члены

Comment: фанктор? вроде всегда был функтором. Но поможет ли это задаче... даже не знаю

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, сейчась исправлю!

Comment: @KoVadim,  я тоже не знаю, но я руководствовался желанием автора вопроса :   "Во втором способе два раза повторяется цикл. Это плохо, так как при изменении параметров цикла (например параметра max), придется править в двух местах и легко забыть, что надо поправить и в другом цикле."

Comment: это ложно предположение автора - max (это конечно немного плохое имя), меняется в одном месте.

Comment: Этот вариант с функтором то же самое что второй вариант в вопросе. При изменении параметров цикла надо править в двух местах, что не очень хорошо.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, не согласен, у меня времени очень мало  для дальнейших комментарий - извените...